# this.forceUpdate() not re-rendering dynamically created components

Tags: reactjs

Assume all the various components have been defined.

In my react component, I want the button click to trigger the appending of a new `TextBox` component in my dynamically created `questions` component. When I tested the button click with `forceUpdate()`, a `TextBox` was successfully appended to `questions` but there was no apparent addition of a new `TextBox` element. I tested whether the component was actually re-rendering by using `<h4>Random number : {Math.random()}</h4>` and it turns out the component was doing so, as the number changed every time I pressed the button.

Is something being done wrong?

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.questions = [];
  this.questions.push(<TextBox key={this.questions.length}/>);
  this.createTextBox = this.createTextBox.bind(this);
  this.loadTextBox = this.loadTextBox.bind(this);
}

createTextBox() {
  this.questions.push(<TextBox key={this.questions.length}/>);
  this.forceUpdate();
}

loadTextBox() {
  return (this.questions);
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h4>Random number : {Math.random()}</h4>
      {this.loadTextBox()}
      <ButtonToolbar className="add-question">
        <DropdownButton bsSize="large" title="Add" id="dropdown-size-large" dropup pullRight>
          <MenuItem eventKey="1" onClick={this.createTextBox}>Text Box</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You mean visually there are new Textboxes but there are no new text boxes in dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only items inside `this.state` are properly monitored by React on whether or not a rerender should occur. Using `this.forceUpdate` does not check to see if `this.questions` has been changed.

Use `this.questions` as `this.state.questions`. When you do this, do not mutate `this.state.questions`. Instead, make a new copy of it and use `this.setState` on it.

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    questions: [<TextBox key={0}/>]
  }
  this.createTextBox = this.createTextBox.bind(this);
  this.loadTextBox = this.loadTextBox.bind(this);
}

createTextBox() {
  const newQuestions = [...this.state.questions, <TextBox key={this.questions.length}/>]
  // or you can use 
  // const newQuestions = this.state.questions.concat(<TextBox key={this.questions.length + 1}/>)
  this.setState({questions: newQuestions})
}

loadTextBox() {
  return (this.state.questions);
}
```

One important thing to note is that `this.forceUpdate` is almost never needed. If you find yourself using it, you are writing your code in an unoptimal way. I made some modifications to your code regarding how keys are assigned. The only reason you should ever be checking for updates is if something in `this.state` has changed, which involves using `this.setState`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @JemSavvy Always happen to help. Best of luck on your app